# ElasticSearch NEST concat filters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I want to apply filters for my SearchDescriptor step by step. I wrote next code for that:

```
public abstract class BaseSearchModel
        {
            public virtual async Task Apply<T>(SearchDescriptor<T> searchDescriptor,
                        bool isInternalUser)
                        where T : class
            {
                if (isInternalUser)
                {
                    searchDescriptor.Query(q => q
                                    .Bool(bq => bq
                                        .Filter(
                                            f => f & f.Terms(t => t.Field(new Field("requiredAccessLevel")).Terms("admin", "guest"))
                                            )))
                }
                else
                {
                    searchDescriptor.Query(q => q
                                    .Bool(bq => bq
                                        .Filter(
                                            f => f & f.Terms(t => t.Field(new Field("requiredAccessLevel")).Terms("guest"))
                                            )))
                }
            }
        }

        public class FilmsSearchModel : BaseSearchModel
        {
            public override async Task Apply<T>(SearchDescriptor<T> searchDescriptor,
                                    bool isInternalUser)
                                    where T : class
            {
                base.Apply(searchDescriptor, isInternalUser);
                searchDescriptor.Query(q => q
                                                    .Bool(bq => bq
                                                        .Filter(
                                                            f => f & f.Terms(t => t.Field(new Field("contentType")).Terms("films"))
                                                            )))
            }
        }
```

but when I apply my search model to SearchDescriptor by the next way:

```
FilmsSearchModel fsm = FilmsSearchModel();
await _client.SearchAsync<T>(searchDescriptor => fsm.Apply(searchDescriptor, true))
```

only last filter sends to ElasticSearch.
Can anybody explain me, what's wrong and how I can concatenate multiple filters?